# Open source USB redirector software from my Laptop to a VM hosted on Vmware ESXi

Tags: esxi

I have a VMWare ESXi host and Vms created on it. I also have a fingerprint scanner attached to my laptop. I want to access it over the VM created on VmwareESXI. After browsing the web, I found that I need USB redirector software to achieve my end goal.  Is there an open-source version available? Or is there any other solution to achieve my end goal? All thoughts are welcomed.
My laptop has Windows 10 OS, and my VM is Windows server 2019

Comment: Have you looked at the USB tools built in to ESXi?

Comment: The problem here is that the native USB tools are useful when the scanner is directly attached to the USB Host. In my case, the fingerprint scanner will be attached to my Laptop and I will be connecting to the VM using RDP. So I need some help on how can I use the scanner attached to my Laptop  in the software installed on the VM when I am connected to VM via RDP

Comment: What about USB-over-IP? I remember trying to solve this problem in a way quite a few years ago, with software licensing dongles and virtualized servers on VMware, and that's what I found that seemed the best solution.

Comment: I were using USB over IP back in the days. I am not sure that there is open source tools, which will allow you to do that. There are commercial tools, I was using it (I don't remember the name of this software).